# How do I distinguish "module not found" from "module threw exception" on ImportError?

Tags: python, importerror

In Python, `import does_not_exist` raises `ImportError`, and

```
import exists
```

`exists.py`:

```
import does_not_exist
```

will also raise `ImportError`.

How should I tell the difference in code?

Comment: Can you clarify? I don't see the problem from your example

Comment: JimB the code wants to know if a module simply doesn't exist so it can look for it by iterating through the list of plugins. If the module does exist, but throws its own ImportError, it should re-raise the original ImportError.

Comment: Ahh, I see. In that case, I think I like @kaizer.se's answer. There are some import time hooks you can make use of, and modulefinder, but I think this works well.

Comment: Let's hope there will be [`ModuleNotFound` exception](http://hg.python.org/releasing/3.3.5/file/1f2c16c7ecc2/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#l1526)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only method I know is to check if the toplevel modulename "exists" is in the Exception's message or not:

```
try:
  import exists
except ImportError as exc:
  if "exists" in str(exc):
     pass
  else:
     raise
```

Could this be a feature request for Python's ImportError? Having a variable for the module name would certainly be convenient..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tb_next of the traceback. It will be different from None if the exception occured on another module

```
import sys
try:
    import exists
except Exception, e:
    print "None on exists", sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next == None

try:
    import notexists
except Exception, e:
    print "None on notexists", sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next == None

>>> None on exists False
>>> None on notexists True
```

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately it breaks when you're running under `rpdb2`'s import hook.